# Simple extending csr matrix by adding a column

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I have this code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
q = csr_matrix([[1.], [0.]])
ones = np.ones((2, 1))
```

and now how to add ones column to matrix q to have result shape (2, 2)?
(matrix q is sparse and I don't want to change type from csr)

Comment: That is not possible without converting to another format in-between. Efficient adding of a row is possible in CSR, but efficient adding of a column is impossible. If you need to add columns, you should better use another format.

Comment: ok - so transposing, adding row and transposing again should to the trick but it's not so performant...

Comment: ok I found the answer... scipy.sparse.vstack and scipy.sparse.hstack

Comment: Yes, that will work, but it will convert to another format internally, then convert back. Depending on your application, this may or may not be sensible.

Comment: Check `sparse/construct.py` for the code.  `hstack` uses `bmat`.  There's a fast version for columns of `csc`.  The rest convert to `coo`, join the attributes and make a new array via the `coo` style of input.

Answer (score 1):

The code for `sparse.hstack` is

```
return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
```

for `bmat`, then `blocks` is a `1xN` array.  If they are all `csc`, it does a fast version of stack:

```
A = _compressed_sparse_stack(blocks[0,:], 1)
```

Conversely `sparse.vstack` with `csr` matrixes does

```
A = _compressed_sparse_stack(blocks[:,0], 0)
```

In effect given how data is stored in a `csr` matrix it it relatively easy to add rows (or columns for `csc`) (I can elaborate if that needs explanation).

Otherwise `bmat` does:

```
# convert everything to COO format
# calculate total nnz
data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=dtype)
for B in blocks:
    data[nnz:nnz + B.nnz] = B.data
return coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=shape).asformat(format)
```

In other words it gets the `data`, `row`, `col` values for each block, concatenates them, makes a new `coo` matrix, and finally converts it to the desire format.

`sparse` readily converts between formats.  Even the display of a matrix can involve a conversion - to coo for the `(i,j) d` format, to csr for dense/array.  `sparse.nonzero` converts to `coo`.  Most math converts to `csr`. A `csr` is transposed by converting it to a `csc` (without change of attribute arrays).   Much of the conversion is done in compiled code so you don't see delays.

Adding columns directly to `csr` format is a lot of work.  All 3 attribute arrays have to be modified row by row.  Again I could go into detail if needed.